# У меня есть задание не я не понимаю как вивести в цикле остачу от деления через условний оператор?

Tags: c++, c

[image: Вот фото кода]

Когда я пишу float k=a%i у меня ошибка как сделать правильно тип или какой он нужен бить? Просто мне нужно вивести числа из цикла которие при деление 40 на i будут делиться без остачи.

Comment: Операция получения остатка `%` - только для целых чисел. Для чисел с плавающей точкой - [`fmod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmod). И еще - по-русски не "остача", а "остаток".

Comment: "у меня ошибка" - предлагаете нам ее угадать? деление на 0?

Comment: @Harry, так там вычисляется целочисленный остаток, просто потом зачем-то float присваивается

Comment: @Zhihar Меня сбило `a = 40.0`... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

т.е. ваш код выводит только 0, может вам надо вывести все таки `i`?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
    if (a % i == 0) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

тогда код хотя бы похож на код поиска делителей числа `a`

Comment: Спасибо большое